# Where can I find documentation on the scaling levels of Open Railway Map tiles

Tags: xyz-tiles

I am using the Open Railway Map xyz tiles (https://a.tiles.openrailwaymap.org/standard/{z}/{x}/{y}.png). The level of detail changes at various zoom levels. Where can I learn what the defined levels of detail are at each zoom level?

Comment: What about the legend on the left side of the map, which changes with zoom: https://www.openrailwaymap.org/

Comment: That legend does not exist in XYZ tiles plugin in QGIS, unless I am missing a feature.

Comment: Of course not, but the question was "Where can I learn ...?".